# SQL Server - How join multiple tables in different databases with NO duplicates (simple query)

Tags: sql-server-2008, join, duplicates

First, I am a novice so this is probably really simple.  I just have not been able to figure it out.

My problem: I have one table that has 560782 rows of data [this should be the result when I'm done].  When I join it to another table (different database) to get the provname, I get 582634 rows.  I know that is because there are sometimes two entries for the same provid.  I ONLY need the single instance for the provid.  The bigger problem comes when I add the third table from a different database.  I honestly don't know how many rows it is returning, because I had to stop it after about 20 minutes. I am pretty sure it is duplicating 580782x582634.  I believe there is some way of using **DISTINCT** to help, but I am not sure where/how.

```
/* add prov name and plan name to data set for analysis */
SELECT 
    a.pcp_id, a.HMO_ID, a.MEM_MONTH, a.MEM_YEAR, a.patient_id, 
    b.prov_name, b.org_name, b.serv_area_name, a.PLAN_NUMBER, 
    c.PLAN_TYPE_NAME  
FROM 
    IDA.dbo.ida_Mem_Mo a
INNER JOIN
    AMG.dbo.tbl_AMG_PROV b ON a.pcp_id = b.prov_id
LEFT JOIN 
    IDX.dbo.IDX_ENROLL c ON a.PLAN_NUMBER = c.PLAN_NUMBER
WHERE
    a.HMO_ID = 6 
    AND (a.MEM_DATE > CONVERT(DATETIME, '2014-12-31 00:00:00', 102))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I have one table that has 560782 rows of data [this should be the
>   result when I'm done]. When I join it to another table (different
>   database) to get the provname, I get 582634 rows. I know that is
>   because there are sometimes two entries for the same provid. I ONLY
>   need the single instance for the provid.

to handle that you need to get distinct values of prov_id inside a subquery ( will work only if that table AMG.dbo.tbl_AMG_PROV has a unique  prov_id for every combination of prov_name, org_name, serv_area_name

```
SELECT a.pcp_id, a.HMO_ID, a.MEM_MONTH, a.MEM_YEAR, a.patient_id, .....
FROM IDA.dbo.ida_Mem_Mo a
inner join
(
select distinct prov_id, prov_name, org_name, serv_area_name from 
AMG.dbo.tbl_AMG_PROV b  ON a.pcp_id=b.prov_id
) b ON a.pcp_id=b.prov_id
```

similarly for the other table IDX.dbo.IDX_ENROLL

but i need to know the schema and relationship to be able to help you further

Comment: In the AMG table, the prov_name, some times appears twice; same prov_id physical different address (everything else is the same).   I am unsure what you mean by schema? Sorry. This is all very new to me.

Comment: thats why you are getting duplicates ... so if some prov_id have more than 1  entries which one do you want to select ? We need to know the rule. Some times we can figure this out using the table layout (Schema). Right click on the table pick script table as --> create to --> file . SAve and copy/paste that in your main post by editing it and formatting it. You should also post some sample data for relevant columns. And explains the rules. OTherwise it will be very difficult to help.

Comment: ok.  I am out of the office now.  I will do this when I'm back in tomorrow. It honestly does not matter which row is chosen,  as they are the same provider.